# ios 7 UINavigationBar is above content when using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Auto Layout in a storyboard to position a UICollectionView. I have created a vertical spacing between Top Layout Guide and the CollectionView. But the collection view still starts underneath the navigation bar. Even the prototype cell also has extra padding. Please see images below.

Interface Builder:
[image]

Simulator View:
[image]

The content should start below the navigation bar but as the user scrolls the content should go under the navigation bar. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please describe how you build the View, what elements do you use in which order!? I am trying to put a UINavigationBar in a UICollectionView and it will not allow me to add the NavigationBar?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your storyboard go to View Controller properties, and make sure that Under Top Bars option is unchecked.

[image]

Also in most cases you want to have opaque navigation bar.

Comment: I want to have the effect of the content scrolling behind navigation bar. How can I do that?

Comment: Wow... you saved my day. 'Under Top Bars' is the thing! Thank you man

Comment: I'm surprised that View Controllers don't have this unchecked by default...

Comment: view controller has .edgesForExtendedLayout property. you can assign it as

`self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .top`